# How to remove initial background image when starting a cocos2d-html project?

Tags: cocos2d-html5

Initially when a cocos2d-html5 project starts (in the web browser), there is a background image showing cocos2d.

How does one remove or change it ?

This appears just after the loading screen. I cannot find a reference to it anywhere in code.

Answer (score 0):

It's created in `frameworks/cocos2d-html5/cocos2d/core/scenes/CCLoaderScene.js`

```js
//image move to CCSceneFile.js
var fontSize = 24, lblHeight =  -logoHeight / 2 + 100;
if(cc._loaderImage){
    //loading logo
    cc.loader.loadImg(cc._loaderImage, {isCrossOrigin : false }, function(err, img){
        logoWidth = img.width;
        logoHeight = img.height;
        self._initStage(img, cc.visibleRect.center);
    });
    fontSize = 14;
    lblHeight = -logoHeight / 2 - 10;
}
```

And the cocos2d logo is a base64 image store in variable `cc._loaderImage`.

`cc._loaderImage` is defined in `frameworks/cocos2d-html5/Base64Images.js`